# How to get client IP address in Laravel 5+

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I am trying to get the client's IP address in Laravel.

It is easy to get a client's IP in PHP by using `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`. It is working fine in core PHP, but when I use the same thing in Laravel,  it returns the server IP instead of the visitor's IP.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

Looking at the [Laravel API](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_ip):

```
Request::ip();
```

Internally, it uses the `getClientIps` method from the [Symfony Request Object](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Request.php#L792):

```
public function getClientIps()
{
    $clientIps = array();
    $ip = $this->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR');
    if (!$this->isFromTrustedProxy()) {
        return array($ip);
    }
    if (self::$trustedHeaders[self::HEADER_FORWARDED] && $this->headers->has(self::$trustedHeaders[self::HEADER_FORWARDED])) {
        $forwardedHeader = $this->headers->get(self::$trustedHeaders[self::HEADER_FORWARDED]);
        preg_match_all('{(for)=("?\[?)([a-z0-9\.:_\-/]*)}', $forwardedHeader, $matches);
        $clientIps = $matches[3];
    } elseif (self::$trustedHeaders[self::HEADER_CLIENT_IP] && $this->headers->has(self::$trustedHeaders[self::HEADER_CLIENT_IP])) {
        $clientIps = array_map('trim', explode(',', $this->headers->get(self::$trustedHeaders[self::HEADER_CLIENT_IP])));
    }
    $clientIps[] = $ip; // Complete the IP chain with the IP the request actually came from
    $ip = $clientIps[0]; // Fallback to this when the client IP falls into the range of trusted proxies
    foreach ($clientIps as $key => $clientIp) {
        // Remove port (unfortunately, it does happen)
        if (preg_match('{((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)\:\d+}', $clientIp, $match)) {
            $clientIps[$key] = $clientIp = $match[1];
        }
        if (IpUtils::checkIp($clientIp, self::$trustedProxies)) {
            unset($clientIps[$key]);
        }
    }
    // Now the IP chain contains only untrusted proxies and the client IP
    return $clientIps ? array_reverse($clientIps) : array($ip);
}
```

Comment: Using the Request object doesn't work for me, it returns the address of my Homestead server. 192.168.10.10 which is obviously not my IP address.

Comment: @VinceKronlein for your case check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41769505/3437790

Comment: @VinceKronlein in your case it was very correct. Because you were accessing Homestead, in your LOCAL network, you had tje 192. IP. if you were accessing someone else's homestead server, through the internet, your IP would go out through your ISP and your public one would be used.

Comment: To get current user ip in php, laravel
  
\Request::ip();

OR 
  
$request->ip();

Answer (score 155):

> **Note:** This answer is outdated and dangerous. `Request::ip()` will, since Laravel 5.5, return the correct IP address if [configured to trust the load balancer's headers](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies). The "custom method" presented here allows clients to set [any IP address they like](https://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/11/anatomy-of-attack-how-i-hacked.html).

If you are under a load balancer, Laravel's `\Request::ip()` **always** returns the balancer's IP:

```
            echo $request->ip();
            // server IP

            echo \Request::ip();
            // server IP

            echo \request()->ip();
            // server IP

            echo $this->getIp(); //see the method below
            // client IP
```

This custom method returns the real client IP:

```
public function getIp(){
    foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key){
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true){
            foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip){
                $ip = trim($ip); // just to be safe
                if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false){
                    return $ip;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return request()->ip(); // it will return the server IP if the client IP is not found using this method.
}
```

In addition to this, I suggest you be very careful using Laravel's **throttle** middleware: It uses Laravel's `Request::ip()` as well, so all your visitors will be identified as the same user and you will hit the throttle limit very quickly. I experienced this in a live environment and this caused big issues.

To fix this:

Illuminate\Http\Request.php

```
    public function ip()
    {
        //return $this->getClientIp(); //original method
        return $this->getIp(); // the above method
    }
```

You can now also use `Request::ip()`, which should return the real IP in production.

Comment: is correct the if(filter_var...) inside second foreach ? this code will be never executed.

Comment: @Mistre83 Yes you are right, I think it's a test oversight. I update it!

Comment: this actually works with laravel 5.4
Please consider making PR on github. I think this should be default behavior

Comment: This worked a treat in Laravel 5.3 when the Laravel request object's ip() method kept returning 127.0.0.1

Comment: Cant you fix this with trusted proxys? - https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me more than I thought I needed. But there is a better way to solve this problem, see my answer.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev not sure about the `protected $proxies = '*';` in terms of security, when reading the headers is harmless

Comment: I think one pipe "|" sign is missing after FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE
 FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE
other than this it work fine for me Thanks @SebastienHorin

Comment: if the client use VPN, is this code will retrieve the fake IP address or the real IP address?

Comment: To answer @SyamsoulAzrien, might not be a possible due to the user's IP's present before the request has been done, thus it's the vpn's ip was the present

Comment: For the second part of the answer, is it wise to edit the core framework file (Illuminate\Http\Request.php)? Because every time you do composer install on another machine, this will not apply.

Answer (score 81):

Use `request()->ip()`.

From what I understand, since Laravel 5 it's advised/good practice to use the global functions like:

```
response()->json($v);
view('path.to.blade');
redirect();
route();
cookie();
```

And, if anything, when using the functions instead of the static notation my IDE doesn't light up like a Christmas tree.

Comment: You are right that `request` is a "global" function - it's one of the global helper functions provided by laravel. However, the Request facade, isn't static (nor is the method ip) - `request()->foo`, and `Reqest::foo` and `$request->foo` are all identical. Have a look at this gist for an example: https://gist.github.com/cjke/026e3036c6a10c672dc5

Comment: Yeah I know :) But it's written in the static syntax `::`. My IDE tends to light up light a christmas tree with those. The global functions just 'look' cleaner ;-) But to each his own!

Comment: Fair enough - both are equally correct. I just thought the bit where you said "it's not `Request::ip` might be misleading

Comment: You're absolutely right! Re-reading it I notice the second sentence should have read: `And since Laravel 5 it's (from what I understand) [recommended] to use the global functions like`

My bad! That should have put things into perspective.

Comment: The problem is that these global functions aren't easily testable—they can't be mocked.  Façades can be.  I try to avoid global functions, since it means digging through to global function source to mock its calls, which is extra work, annoying, and shouldn't be my responsibility.

Comment: Although `request()->ip()` is correct, the surrounding text is really misleading - especially to say "it's not `Request::ip`.

Comment: @Chris Thanks, you're absolutely right. Edited for clarity!

Comment: @hackel Good point! Thanks for explaining that. I hardly ever mock so don't run into that problem but that definitely seems like something to be aware of!

Comment: $request->ip() L5.1

Answer (score 37):

Add namespace

```
use Request;
```

Then call the function

```
Request::ip();
```

Comment: If you have use namespace    :-->  use Illuminate\Http\Request;   **bold** Rename namespace for request since both will clash

Comment: The original answer is correct. You need to import `use Request` because you're trying to use the Facade. The namespace you provided is for the underlying class. If you import that you will get an error because `ip()` can't be called statically, that's what the facade is for.

Comment: If you're going to bother importing the class, you should use the actual façade, not the alias: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request`.  If not, just use `\Request::`.

Comment: Request::ip(); return me Server Ip. I want network Ip address . It  is possible ???

Answer (score 26):

There are two things to take care of:

1. Get a helper function that returns a `Illuminate\Http\Request` and call the `->ip()` method:

   ```
   request()->ip();
   ```
2. Think of your server configuration, it may use a proxy or `load-balancer`, especially in an AWS ELB configuration.

If this is your case you need to follow "[Configuring Trusted Proxies](https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies)" or maybe even set a "Trusting All Proxies" option.

Why? Because being your server will be getting your proxy/`load-balancer` IP instead.

If you are on the AWS balance-loader, go to `App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies` and make `$proxies` declaration look like this:

```
protected $proxies = '*';
```

Now test it and celebrate because you just saved yourself from having trouble with  throttle middleware. It also relies on `request()->ip()` and without setting "TrustProxies" up, you could have all your users blocked from logging in instead of blocking only the culprit's IP.

And because throttle middleware is not explained properly in the documentation, I recommend watching "[laravel 5.2 tutorial for beginner, API Rate Limiting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJueNT4yZaA)"

Tested in Laravel 5.7

Answer (score 23):

For Laravel 5 you can use the Request object. Just call its `ip()` method, something like:

```
$request->ip();
```

Answer (score 19):

In Laravel 5

```
public function index(Request $request) {
  $request->ip();
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I tested in Laravel 8.x and you can use:

```
$request->ip()
```

For getting the client's IP address.

Answer (score 8):

In Laravel 5.4 we can't call ip static.  This a correct way to get the IP of the user:

```
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function contactUS(Request $request)
    {
        echo $request->ip();
        return view('page.contactUS');
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

This below function will help you to give the client's IP address -

```
public function getUserIpAddr(){
       $ipaddress = '';
       if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
           $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
       else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
           $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
       else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
           $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
       else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
           $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
       else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
           $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
       else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
           $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
       else
           $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';    
       return $ipaddress;
    }
```

Comment: This answer is WRONG. Read https://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/11/anatomy-of-attack-how-i-hacked.html

Answer (score 7):

If you are still getting 127.0.0.1 as the IP, you need to add your "proxy", but be aware that you have to change it before going into production!

Read "[Configuring Trusted Proxies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies)".

And add this:

```
class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $proxies = '*';
```

Now `request()->ip()` gives you the correct IP.

Comment: @Huzaifa99 weird it worked for me for a while, not it's not working! How weird (did you find another solution?)

Answer (score 5):

If you want client IP and your server is behind aws elb, then user the following code. Tested for laravel 5.3

```
$elbSubnet = '172.31.0.0/16';
Request::setTrustedProxies([$elbSubnet]);
$clientIp = $request->ip();
```

Comment: Not working anymore, now "trustedHeaderSet" is neeed

Comment: for "recent" laravel versions, see the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies

Answer (score 0):

```
   protected function getIp(){
        foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key){
            if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true){
                foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip){
                    if (filter_var(trim($ip), FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false){
                        return $ip;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return request()->ip(); 
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple layer proxies just like CDN + Load Balancer.
Using Laravel Request::ip() function will get right-most proxy IP but not client IP.
You may try following solution.

app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php

```
protected $proxies = ['0.0.0.0/0'];
```

Reference: https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy/issues/107#issuecomment-373065215

Answer (score -1):

I used the Sebastien Horin function getIp and request()->ip() (at global request), because to localhost the getIp function return null:

`$this->getIp() ?? request()->ip();`

The getIp function:

```
public function getIp(){
foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key){
    if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true){
        foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip){
            $ip = trim($ip); // just to be safe
            if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false){
                return $ip;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The closing bracket is outside of the code block.  Minor problem, but nice.

Comment: Great observation @SScotti

Comment: This answer is wrong. Read https://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/11/anatomy-of-attack-how-i-hacked.html

Answer (score -1):

**Solution 1:** You can use this type of function for getting client IP

```
public function getClientIPaddress(Request $request) {
    $clientIp = $request->ip();
    return $clientIp;
}
```

**Solution 2:** if the solution1 is **not providing accurate IP** then you can use this function for getting visitor real IP.

```
 public function getClientIPaddress(Request $request) {

    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])) {
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
        $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
    }
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
        $clientIp = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
        $clientIp = $forward;
    }
    else{
        $clientIp = $remote;
    }

    return $clientIp;
 }
```

**N.B:** When you have used **load-balancer**/**proxy-server** in your production server then you need to used **solution 2** for getting real visitor ip.

Comment: This solution 2 should never be used. Please refer to the accepted answer for the correct approach

Answer (score -1):

This solution I used in my project. I found other solutions here either incomplete or too complex to understand.

```
if (! function_exists('get_visitor_IP'))
{
    /**
     * Get the real IP address from visitors proxy. e.g. Cloudflare
     *
     * @return string IP
     */
    function get_visitor_IP()
    {
        // Get real visitor IP behind CloudFlare network
        if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])) {
            $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
            $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
        }

        // Sometimes the `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` can be used by proxy servers
        $ip = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
           return $ip;
        }

        // Sometimes the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` can contain more than IPs 
        $forward_ips = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        if ($forward_ips) {
            $all_ips = explode(',', $forward_ips);

            foreach ($all_ips as $ip) {
                if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE)){
                    return $ip;
                }
            }
        }

        return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is WRONG. Read https://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/11/anatomy-of-attack-how-i-hacked.html

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel 7&8, I am using  below methoths.

**In Controller**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $request->ip();
    return view('users.index');
}
```

**In Blade**

```
Request::ip()
```

**Anywhere**

```
request()->ip()
```