# Get User IP address in laravel with similar method to HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get my users IP address'.

I found this article [How to get Client Ip Address in Laravel 5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268683/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-laravel-5-1)

The above mentioned article uses the `Request::ip();`

However, this method returns my servers IP address. From what I can understand from other sources, this happens when the site is localhost - but the site is hosted and is live on a server.

This site is live and online, but it might refer to `localhost`, as the site might be sitting on its own server (I dont have any experience in server config to know if this is true or not, just a guess).

When I connect to the DB Host, I do so using `localhost` referencing as well, and not something like `mysql.phpmyadmin.hosting.com` as DB Host. Therefore, my guess is, that the `Request::ip();` returns the server ip, because the site somehow is sitting localhost.

However, if I use $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']; I get the correct IP address.

Now to my final question: **Is this safe to use?** Is there another way to use a Laravel function to make this request?

From what I can understand, the $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']; can have security holes, according to [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php).

**Can I use `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];` safely without worrying? If not, what other way could I go, to get the users IP address safely?**

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is more reliable than `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`.

Comment: Are you using a load balancer that redirects requests to your web server by any chance?

Comment: @EliSadoff `Request::ip()` uses `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. In a proxied/load-balanced scenario, like OP's, the remote address of the connection will be the proxy/load balancer.

Comment: @ceejayoz Oh that makes sense. Unfortunately using `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` allows for easy spoofing.

Comment: some hoster configuration use a proxy. So the `REMOTE_ADDR` is in this example the server ip. You can use `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`. Its not a big deal (for me).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The risk with `X-Forwarded-For` is that a user could create the header themselves, and thus pass along any IP they wish.

The solution is to only trust the header when `REMOTE_ADDR` is that of your trusted proxy. There's a [Laravel package](https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy) (edit: now [part of Laravel core](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.html)) that lets you enforce this restriction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I see. However, would there be any serious security holes for X-Forwarded-For? What I am doing, is simply saving the IP address in a database. Im thinking that if they change the IP address, it wouldn't be a big deal, just some counting inconsistencies, but nothing serious - however if this leads to them being able to somehow access the database or other serious security holes, by implementing code in the database, then X-Forwarded-For wouldn't work at all ofc. Looking forward to your answer :)

Comment: @Patrick Just data integrity, to my knowledge. If you don't care that a user might spoof an IP that winds up in your database, it should be safe.

Comment: Ive tried to do what you are mentioning, by tampering the data, using something like "tamper data" - but it seems to be more advanced to do this and just a simple tamper? Please correct me if im wrong :)

Comment: @Patrick It takes some doing. It sounds like your host has a proxy or load-balancer in front of your server, so attempting to set an `X-Forwarded-For` is going to be ignored by that device. You'd have to bypass it by hitting the server itself directly. There *are* more subtle vulnerabilities you might have in your code, so you should still exercise caution - http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/11/anatomy-of-attack-how-i-hacked.html for example, was a vulnerabilty right here on SO.