# How to get users IP address in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

How can you get users IP address in Laravel 5.4?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268683/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-laravel-5-1

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We appreciate that you might be new, but we do expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, where is the code you wrote to test what you learned? If you didn't write code, why not? If you did, what is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered, along with the explanation of the problem, and the minimal input data and the expected result? Without that it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 12):

```
$request->ip();
Request::ip();
request()->ip();
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
Request::ip();
```

[Laravel Request API](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_ip)