# AWS - Why myIp is changed when pass load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm creating web app with EC2, using Load balancer and ACM to get https at Application Load balancer layer, load balancer and EC2 connect with port 80.  Server is Apache, code with Laravel.  Networking look like Ok, I created an Ip filter layer to set limit access to admin control panel.
I dont know why but sometime my access Ip changed when pass load balancer. For example I checked My Ip and got 125.9.4.168 but when I dump in Laravel code, It return 172.31.34.117.
I don't know why but It's very strange.
Some body know why?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 125.9.4.168 IP address is your public IP, and the 172.31.34.117 is the private address.

IPs beginning in 10, 172, and 192.168. are all private addresses.

See Wikipedia's private network article for more information. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Hope this helps.

Comment: when I didn't use load balancer and direct point domain name to Elastic IP, It was Ok and always return public Ip. Maybe I have to change php code to get public Ip. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found an article that same with my problem. Because my app under Load balancer so use Laravel User Agent to get Ip, Ip was returned with private Ip.

[How to get client IP address in Laravel 5+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268683/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-laravel-5)