# Laravel - Get website unique visitor count

Tags: php, laravel

I want to collect the unique amount of visitors on my website and store them in a database. Even when someone without an account accesses the website the visitor count goes up. How can I accomplish this?

I know I have to fetch the users IP address or something along those lines but I don't know how to fetch the IP address of a user without an account when the page loads

Currently I have this DB table

```
Visitors
 - ip
 - date_visited
```

Route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $ip = Request::ip();
    return view('welcome', compact('ip'));
});
```

Comment: checkout this https://github.com/jenssegers/agent

Comment: Have a look into Google analytics

Comment: What do you mean by "don't know how to fetch the IP address"? What have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `Request::ip()` to get the ip;

```php
$ip = Request::ip();
```

For Laravel 5.4 +:

```php
$ip = $request->ip();
// or
$ip = request()->ip();
```

And I think you can use **middleware** and **redis** to calculate this count, this will reduce the db's pressure.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however I add this code to my route (See updated post) and turn my webhook on. It always says 127.0.0.1 even though my phone has a different IP. I asked a friend to access the website aswell and it says 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Rainierlaan do u test it locally?

Comment: I know it has been 3 years but wanted to say that it worked :P

Answer (score 3):

One good solution in this case is to create an `middleware` that tracks all your users. We can put any kind of business logic in the `middleware`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class TrackUser
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        /* You can store your user data with model, db or whatever...
           Here I use a repository that contains all my model queries. */
        $repository = resolve('App\Repositories\TrackUserRepository');

        $repository->addUser([
            'ip'   => request()->ip(),
            'date' => now(),
        ]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then add the `middleware` to `App\Kernel.php`:

- Add it to `$middleware` if you want it to be an global middleware that runs on every request.
- Add it to `$middlewareGroups` if you want it to only run on every `web`-route.
- Add it to `$routeMiddleware` if you want to specify in `routes/web.php` when the middleware should apply.

You should also consider moving any logic in the `middleware` inside a "`try` `catch`"-statement, it minimized the risk that your user gets halted by any errors caused be the "tracking"-code.

```
try {
    $repository = resolve('App\Repositories\TrackUserRepository');

    $repository->addUser([
        'ip'   => request()->ip(),
        'date' => now(),
    ]);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Do nothing or maybe log error
}

return $next($request);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use combination of `user_agent` and `ip` to have more accurate results, many user may have the same IP but usually have different user agents:

```php
request()->userAgent();
request()->ip();
```

---

Alternatively if you're using `web` middleware (not `api`), Laravel starts a session for each client. You can change your session driver and use `database` instead of default `file`.

This way Laravel will store a record for each client on `sessions` table containing all info you need and even more:

```php
Schema::create('sessions', function ($table) {
    $table->string('id')->unique();
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
    $table->text('user_agent')->nullable();
    $table->text('payload');
    $table->integer('last_activity');
});
```

As you can see, there is `ip_address`, `user_agent` and `last_activity`. The `user_id` will be `null` for guest users and has value for authenticated users.

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/session#configuration) to config your session driver to use `database`.

Comment: As a reminder, you can use `$table->ipAddress()` to store IP Address data. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-ipAddress).

Answer (score 0):

As @tsaiKoga mentioned how you will get ip address.

create a new table for for ip address and their visits timestamp .

check IF IP does not exists OR `time()-saved_timestamp > 60*60*24` (for 1 day) ,edit the IP's timestamp to time() (means now) and increase your view one else do nothing!

Moreover, You can get IP by `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

More ways for getting IP is mentioned here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54325153/2667307

Reviewed the comment which returns `127.0.0.1`

Please try:-

```
request()->server('SERVER_ADDR');
```

OR you may use

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
```

OR

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`