# Does the request's ip() method still return the Load Balancer IP address if the app is behind one?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I found a post on here where someone asked how to get the IP address of the client. Then someone mentioned that the request's `ip()` method will return the Load Balancer's IP if it exists: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41769505/17746636

Is this still relevant? Or it's been fixed already, and I will actually get the real client IP and no need for the workaround that he implemented in his answer/

Thanks

Comment: The highly upvoted answer there is **wrong**. All you need to do is properly configure Laravel to trust the load balancer. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies